# Extracting the character part of a string in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, extract, gsub

I am working in R. I have a long vectors of strings. In this vector, I want to find strings like "ABC23-ABC54". Precisely, stings which have same character before and after a "-" and different numbers.

So far I can extract strings with "-" in the middle and assign part1="ABC23", and part2="ABC54". The next step would be to match the character parts, by dropping the numeric parts, but without knowing the exact form and length of the character and numeric part.

How can I do that in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data which illustrates the different edge cases, so we can test provided solutions? For example, should any of  `c("ABC12-ABCD13", "ABC12-AB34", "ABC12-AB12", "ABC12-ABCD12", "ABC12-ABC123", "ABC12-ABC1", "ABC12-ABC", "ABC12-ABC012")` be kept, and if so please explain the reasoning? All are currently ambiguous from your current wording in my opinion.

Comment: In addition to what @CalumYou asks for (an example of the input), you should include an example of the desired output.

Comment: Further, a good "test" of whatever solution you get should (1) match strings you want matched, and (2) not match strings you want ignored. So it is on your shoulders to come up with a small but sufficient test dataset, to include at least one easy, one obscure/hard, and a couple distractors (that should have nothing found). (All representative of the data you are actually using.)

Comment: One example of such string can be: c("CD12","ABC-1","ABC23-GCB54","Tran","CAD1-CAD22", "Tpga1","Tarp21-Tarp3","Tcan5"). Among this list I want to find strings "CAD1-CAD22" and "Tarp21-Tarp3", because the character part is same before and after "-". But I don't know the length of the character part, as well as the numeric part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the digits, read the two fields left into two columns using `read.table` and compare them.

```
ok <- with(read.table(text = gsub("\\d", "", s), sep = "-", as.is = TRUE), V1 == V2)
ok
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

s[ok]
## [1] "ABC12-ABC123" "ABC12-ABC1"   "ABC12-ABC"    "ABC12-ABC012"
```

### Note

We used the following test input taken from a comment below the question.

```
s <- c("ABC12-ABCD13", "ABC12-AB34", "ABC12-AB12", "ABC12-ABCD12", "ABC12-ABC123", 
       "ABC12-ABC1", "ABC12-ABC", "ABC12-ABC012")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly.